# What's the opposite of tar -czvf /opt/nagiosbackup.tar.gz /usr/local/nagios?

Tags: tar

i need to restore a nagios backup created with

```
tar -czvf /opt/nagiosbackup.tar.gz /usr/local/nagios
```

what the EXACT command to launch to restore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tar -xzf file.tar.gz
```

Option `x` to extract, `z` to uncompress a .gz and `f` to tell tar that it's a file.

Edit : if you want to uncompress the archive in a different location you need to use `-C /path/to/directory` or `--directory /path/to/directory`

Comment: what about destination? Can i be sure all file will be restored into the right dest folder ?